# Entity framework DateTime.Now - 7 days C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, frameworks

I try to get the entries of my mssql table from the past 7 days with entity framework in c#.

For that i tried:

```
var query = context.tbl.Where(fld => fld.date >= (DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)));
```

This doesn't work at all.
I thought that if the date from the record was bigger or equal than date.now - 7 days, it should give me back all entries from the past 7 days.

Comment: "doesn't work at all" is not much of a symptom description.

Comment: What sql type is `fld.date` ?

Comment: i think the error message is:
An Exception of type "System.NotSupportedException" is occured in mscorlib.dll.

but don't know if this is the correct error message here.

The sql type in mssql is datetime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DateTime.AddDays()` cannot be converted to a store expression by Entity Framework. I'm assuming this is what you mean when you say it doesn't work?

Try this:

```cs
var dateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
var query = context.tbl.Where(fld => fld.date >= dateTime);
```

Comment: You can also use Entity's own `System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions` library which maps common functions to their native SQL equivalent. It has an `AddDays` function, among others. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.aspx